# Mystery Flutter Warning: Element is implicitly hidden?

Tags: canvas, dart, flutter

Warning:

> Element 'TextStyle' from SDK library 'ui.dart' is implicitly hidden by
>   'text_style.dart'.

Code Extract:

```
 import 'dart:math';
 import 'dart:ui';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    TextSpan span = new TextSpan(style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800], fontSize: 12.0,), text: "Title");
    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout();
    tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(50.0, 300.0));
```

Now this is a warning, and not an error, but I haven't a clue on what this  message even means.  Anybody know how to translate it?  What does this `implicitly hidden` warning message mean?

Comment: My bad. Here is the updated [one](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28023#issuecomment-287792689)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete `import 'dart:ui';` worked for me.

Repost:
The file `text_style.dart` under package `painting` has a `TextStyle`.Also the file `text.dart` under package `ui` has a `TextStyle`. They have the same name, so Dart cannot distinguish, which means "shadowed". Use `import 'dart:ui' as ui;` instead, to tell Dart which `TextStyle` you really want to import. In my situation, what I need to use is the TextStyle under package painting, so delete `import 'dart:ui';` worked for me.

And if you import `package:flutter/material.dart`, the `TextStyle` points to the one under package `painting`. In your case, you also imported the package `ui`, so a "name shadow" happened.

Comment: Awesome answer to the question “how do i make this error go away?”  Unfortunately it doesn’t remotely address the questions stated here. I’m trying to understand how to troubleshoot dart / flutter programs. I want to understand EXACTLY WHAT the error messages mean.  Apologies if I didn’t make that extraordinarily clear in my problem statement.

Comment: The file "text_style.dart" under package painting has a "TextStyle".Also the file "text.dart" under package ui has a "TextStyle". They have the same name, so Dart cannot distinguish, which means "shadowed". Use "import 'dart:ui' as ui;" instead, to tell Dart which "TextStyle" you really want to import. In my situation, what I need to use is the TextStyle under package painting, so delete import 'dart:ui'; worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

A (hopefully) clarifying answer for future reference.

You have at least two options for resolving the import conflict (things are named the same in more than one import and they shadow each other).

1. Use a named import prefix `as`
2. Use the `hide` keyword

Example:
Importing dart:ui might lead to a conflict of TextStyles (A `TextStyle` class exists in both flutter material package and dart ui libraries)

Solutions:

1.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// prefix your use of the ui library with ui (material TextStyle no longer shadowed)
...
ui.TextStyle(... // from dart:ui
ui.ImageFilter(... // from dart:ui
TextStyle(... // from flutter/material
```

2.

```
import 'dart:ui' hide TextStyle;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// hiding the TextStyle from ui lib (material TextStyle no longer shadowed)
...
TextStyle(... // from flutter/material
ImageFilter(... // from dart:ui
```